# Send sqlresult from background to content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-sql

When i send sqlresult from background page to content script (before sending screen) [image: result before sending in console]

it loss data and transforming to [image: result after receiving in console]

it happends only with SqlResultSet, other vriables and simnple array`s sending normally

code in background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        action: "getRight",
        res: results,
        leng: len }, function(response) {});
});
```

code in check.js (content page)

```js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(msg.action) {
        case "getRight":
          console.log(msg.res);
          break;
    }
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: i use Web Sql database

Comment: This isn't related to your actual question, but "Stack Snippets" are for complete html/css/js code.  Short snippets that only work in an extension aren't that, and shouldn't be in a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally found the correct solution of the problem

insteal of sending

```js
res: results
```

i will send

```js
res: results.rows
```

and receiving [image: received sesult in console (content script)]